# Sending APDU Commands in C++

Tags: c++, io, usb, apdu

I want to send a APDU command to my smart card reader in C++ over USB. But I can't find a way to do that. I found a Library for Java called `javax.smartcardio`does it exists a similar but for C++? The only command that I am interested in is to get the firmware version. Which should, according do the manual, be a 8 bytes ASCII string as response from a certain `CLA, INS, P1, P2, Le` command.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not directly in the C++ standard library. There are other libraries that offer access across various platforms. Ultimately they map to the OS API on offer for smart card, or PCSC APIs.

One such project is PCSCLite, https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/

Windows has the SCard family of functions, in particular `SCardTransmit` here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit